# Unable to submit a form to python script in different directory

Tags: python, html, forms, submit

I have an HTML file which creates displays the form and a form handler script written using python in a different directory. The folder looks like this.

```
/home/alpha
           /alphamatters
                        /form_display.html

           /nifty_kite_v2
                        /form_handler.py
```

I am unable to submit the form from `/alphamatters/form_display.html` to `/nifty_kite_v2/form_handler.py`. The form tag I used looks like this.

```
<form action='../nifty_kite_v2/form_handler.py' method='POST'>
```

As soon as I try to submit the form it ends up displaying the below message in browser.

```
The requested URL /nifty_kite_v2/form_handler.py was not found on this server.
```

I also tried absolute file name.

```
<form action='/home/alpha/nifty_kite_v2/form_handler.py' method='POST'>
```

And the result was same. It ended up saying.

```
The requested URL /home/alpha/nifty_kite_v2/form_handler.py was not found on this server.
```

I am unable to figure out what wrong am I doing. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: I used absolute file name and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the absolute path. The html must be running by some web server.  The webserver is understanding path from one way (may be doc root ) the os is understanding it in another way. Or check the doc of your web server

Comment: I agree that relative paths are a dangerous and confusing way to go.